# IntelliJ says invalid item in dependencies list but it is present in maven repo

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

My IntelliJ says that

```
Module <redacted> : invalid item 'Maven: com.ibm:com.ibm.mq.commonservices:7.1.0.6' in the dependencies list
```

But it is in the Maven repo. I tried [this solution](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205450770-Invalid-item-in-dependency-list). But it didnt work. There are 107 such imports. What do I do ?

Comment: Clean the project with mvn clean, close Idea, delete project's/module's iml file and restart the Idea

Comment: Right click on the project pom -> maven -> reimport worked for me.

Comment: deleting .idea folder in project root and opening the project from pom.xml worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its possible that you POM files might have a conflict. Ensure that the required JARs aren't in the exclusion list

Answer (score 0):

Try going to the project settings and making sure that the correct dependencies are selected.

I had a similar problem and solved it once I selected JDK as my module dependency.